# Create aura enabled method

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I want to use aura enabled method. How can I do it?
Input-ID event id
Output-void
Process - update "Escalation Date/Time" with current date

Comment: Could you please add more details like on which object you want to perform the operation and what's the logic and all?

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex.htm) on Lightning Apex Server-Side Controllers? That's a good place to start. For a question to fit the SFSE format, it needs to be [specific and detailed](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I've downvoted this question because it does not show an effort to research your question before it was asked.

Comment: @AuraEnabled
    public static void updateEscalationDateTime(Id eventId) {
        SObject evnt = [SELECT Id, Escalation__c FROM Event WHERE Id = :eventId];
        Event e = new Event (Id=eventId);
                update evnt;
    }
    This is what I was trying but problem is that already I have event id and  I just want when I am clicking Escalate button  update "Escalation Date/Time" with current date/tme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to keep in mind:

1. The methods in your Apex controller must have `@AuraEnabled`
   annotation, and must be `static`.
2. Include your apex controller in component markup.
3. The name of your Controller JS method and apex method must be different.

Here is how:

**Apex Controller:**

```
public with sharing class MyApexController {

    //@AuraEnabled AND static ARE REQUIRED
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void updateEscalationDateTime(Id eventId) {
        SObject o = [SELECT Id, Escalation_Date_Time__c FROM Event__c WHERE EventId__c = :eventId];
        o.Escalation_Date_Time__c = System.now();
        update o;
    }
}
```

**Component Markup:**

```
<aura:component controller="MyApexController">
    <aura:attribute name="eventId" type="String" default="0KK31j0085001R2N"/>
    <!-- YOUR MARKUP -->
</aura:component>
```

**Controller JS:**

```
modifyEscalationDateTime: function(component, event, helper){
    try{
        //THIS IS HOW YOU CREATE/DECLARE/DEFINE YOUR APEX METHOD THAT WILL EVENTUALLY BE ENQUEUED TO BE EXECUTED
        var action = component.get('c.updateEscalationDateTime'); 

        //GET eventId FROM COMPONENT
        var myEventId = component.get('v.eventId');

        //THIS IS HOW YOU PASS PARAMETERS TO YOUR APEX METHOD 
        action.setParams({
            'eventId': myEventId
        });

        //DEFINE WHAT SHOULD HAPPEN AFTER SERVER-SIDE CALL RETURNS
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS")
                console.log('-------> Escalation Date/Time successfully updated'); 
            else 
                console.log('-------> Failed to update Escalation Date/Time!');
        });

        //DON'T FORGET TO ENQUEUE YOUR ACTION
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    } catch(err){
        console.log('-------> ERROR: ' + err + ' ** MESSAGE: ' + err.message + ' ** STACK: ' + err.stack);
    }
},
```

Comment: @AuraEnabled
    public static void updateEscalationDateTime(Id eventId) {
        SObject evnt = [SELECT Id, Escalation__c FROM Event WHERE Id = :eventId];
        Event e = new Event (Id=eventId);
                update evnt;
    }
    This is what I was trying but problem is that already I have event id and  I just want when I am clicking Escalate button  update "Escalation Date/Time" with current date/tme

Comment: Are you saying that eventId already exists in your component, but is not being passed to your apex controller upon clicking that Escalate button? Have you tried putting a debug statement in the first line of your apex controller: system.debug(logginglevel.ERROR, '-------> ' + eventId); and see if it show up in debug log? And also, just before calling your server-side action, in your ControllerJS, try printing the eventId like so: console.log('-------> ' + myEventId); as see if it shows up in your browser logs?

Comment: Thanks for the  support much appreciated
I am sorry I am new in the system so very difficult to understand the issues 
Only having problem on apex controller 
        SObject evnt = [SELECT Id, Escalation__c FROM Event WHERE Id = :eventId];
Already I have event id , 
Can I use like this 
Event e = new Event();
Escalation__c=new update date

Comment: Are you asking how to update an Event object given its id? If so, try something like this: Event e = new Event(Id = eventId, Escalation__c = System.now()); update e;

Comment: Its working now....Thank you for your response to my query. I appreciate the information you have provided me with and I appreciate the prompt reply.